# `relativenumber` in Vim - Switch back and forth in "action" - "number" - "object" operation

Tags: vim

I've been using vim for a while now, but still not proficient with the scripting language.

I want to implement this little widget, calling forth `relativenumber` only when I need it most, which is when I do the "action" - "number" - "object" operation.

For example, when I want to delete 4 lines in my text, I press <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>. It's convenient only when I know it's 4 lines I want to delete. Sometimes it's hard to keep count when the number gets big and `:set nu` doesn't really offer much help.

So what I want to do with it is this: the moment I press down <kbd>d</kbd> the "action", `:set relativenumber` is called. Then I go on to press <kbd>4</kbd>, and only when I have passed it the "object" by pressing the last key in the combination, be it <kbd>d</kbd> or <kbd>w</kbd> or <kbd>l</kbd> or whatever, does it call `:set norelativenumber`, turning back to regular line numbers.

How do I implement that in my `.vimrc`? Or is there already a plugin flowing around that I didn't find?

Comment: do you have `easyMotion` installed?  you could `d<leader><leader>j` + x

Comment: Hey I love that! Thanks for the recommendation! Still, I could learn something from implementing that with VimScript, but your advice is really neat!

Answer (score 0):

Not that easy, because you are about to change vims default mappings and have to deal with recursion.
Here's a list of things you have to consider:

- Write a function which toggles relativenumber/norelativenumber.
- Remap all commands which should use it to call the function first, then
- enter operator-pending mode to catch the second command after the `count`
- avoid recursion while doing that

Here's a starting point, the toggling function:

```
function! ToggleRN()
  if &rnu==1
    set nornu
  elseif &rnu==0
    set rnu
  endif
endfunction
```

*Note*: `&` makes it possible to use Vim's internal settings like variables. Since `relativenumber` is a boolean variable, it's either 1 or 0.

Everything after this starts to be complicated. Good luck with that!

But what's wrong with using `set relativenumber` just all the time?